# Saxon-HE-9.5.1.4 Extracted XML node doesn't contain the root element namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces, saxon

Extracting a particular element(node-set()) Ex. `<BBB>` from the following XML payload ignores the root element namespace to be included in the results

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.sonoasystems.com/schemas/RentACar"> 
   <soapenv:Body>
         <bookCar> 
         <size80K>
            <AAA>
                     <BBB/>
                </AAA>
          </size80K>
         </bookCar>       
      </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Result :
On using Saxon9.5.1.4

```
<BBB xmlns="http://www.sonoasystems.com/schemas/RentACar"/>
```

On using Saxon9.0

```
<BBB xmlns="http://www.sonoasystems.com/schemas/RentACar" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem, your result samples have a `BBB` element, I don't see one at all in your input (only `BCC`).

Comment: My mistake. Its BBB only not BCC.

Comment: Please show us the XSLT.